# OOP & Java: how to generalize from an abstract class?

Tags: java, oop, generics, abstract-class

first of all, i'd like to apologize about my grammar, since english is not my first language, usually i make grammar mistakes...

There is some problem that always prevent me from making generic code:

How do i put an abstract class with abstract methods inside another abstract class? i know abstract classes can't be instantiated, but... isn't there any way to do it with genericity?

**one example**: i have the abstract class **Feline**, this class has several abstract methods. There is another class: the **Cage** class, that can only contain certain amount of one kind of **Feline** objects (say a cage of cats, a cage of tiggers, a cage of lions, etc.)... but how do i do this? i can't instantiate **Felines** inside the **Cage** class... And how do i make a cage of cats?

**Another example**, i've noticed that i can sort a collection of stuff using only two sorting criteria: does this stuff goes after this another stuff? and: does this stuff goes before this another stuff?

So, every sortable stuff must have two boolean methods: "goesAfter(stuff): boolean" and "goesBefore(stuff): boolean", then, i put that stuff on another class through a composition/agreggation relationship, lets call it the LotsOfSortableStuff class, and i would put the "sort(): void" method, this method will use the goesAfter and goesBefore methods from this sortable stuff...

There are lots of things that can be sorted: studentes (by degree), Childs (by height), names (by alfabetic order), etc... The problem is: whenever i want to make a collection of sortable stuff, i have to type over and over the same two methods, and the sorting algorythm!

how do i apply genericity in this kind of problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Polymorphism* allows you to store objects of a *subclass* in containers that are defined to hold *superclass* objects. For instance in your class `Cage` you can have a `List<Feline> felines` that can contain *any* object of a *subclass* of `Feline`

Sorting: For this you can make your *superclass* implement the `Comparator` interface, which requires concrete subclasses to implement a `compareTo` method. For instance if you wanted to sort the `Cage` above by weight of the cats.

Here's an example of what that might look like:

```
  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.ArrayList;  
  import java.util.Collections;

  public abstract class Feline implements Comparable
  {
       protected double weight; 

       protected abstract void whoAmI();

       public void compareTo(Feline other){
          new Double(this.weight).compareTo(new Double(other.weight));
       }

       public static void main(String[] args){
          Cage c = new Cage();

          Feline l = new Lion(400.0);
          Feline t = new Tiger(555.0);

          c.addFeline(l);
          c.addFeline(t);

          for(Feline f : c.getCage()){
             f.whoAmI();
          }
       }
   }

    class Tiger extends Feline 
    {
       public Tiger(double weight){
          super(weight);
       }      

       protected void whoAmI() {
          System.out.println("I'm a Tiger");
       }
    }

    class Lion extends Feline 
    {
       public Lion(double weight){
          super(weight);
       }

       protected void whoAmI() {
          System.out.println("I'm a Lion");
       }
    }

    class Cage
    {
        private List<Feline> felines; 

        public Cage(){
           this.felines = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        public void addFeline(Feline f){ 
           this.felines.add(f); 
        }

        public List<Feline> getCage(){
           return this.felines;
        }

        public void sort(){
           Collections.sort(this.felines);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks! it helped a lot... but, how is the **List** class abble to store **Felines**?

Comment: @RuthGarcía The `List` interface that is defined is Java is already set up to handle *generics*. This way Java programmers can create `List`s of any type, even ones they create themselves.

Comment: Just as a note, your declaration for `Feline` should be `public abstract class Feline implements Comparable<Feline>`

Comment: Another note, you probable should define `Cage` as `Cage<T extends Feline` and then have the `List` be defined as `List<T>`.  Doesn't make sense to have Cats and Tigers in the same cage; the Tigers would eat the Cats.  By allowing the instantiator of `Cage` to define how specific the Cage is (using a higher level abstraction like `Feline`, or something more specific like `Tiger`), they have more power over what gets stored in it.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen , how do I set up a class to handle generics?

Comment: @RuthGarcía You would do what cmbaxter suggested in his comments

Answer (score 0):

For your sorting issue, you should consider making all of your classes that need to be aggregated in lists and then sorted implement the `Comparable` interface.  It's the standard for custom object sorting and Lists of `Comparable` items can be sorted with `Collections.sort` which is pretty simple.